# PHP - Allow Users To Set A Cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'd like to allow users to set a variable through a text form, `$name` for example, then I'd like to set a cookie after they fill the form, so the cookie is set to `$name`.

So if in the text form, the user set `$name = 'John';`

Then I'd like the cookie to be set to `setcookie ("name", "John")`;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
setcookie('name',$_GET['name']);
```

should do it.

Comment: depending of you forms method value the above solution should be eighter $_GET['name'] or $_POST['name']. To solve it in both cases you could also to $_REQUEST['name']

Answer (score 0):

```
    $name  = $_REQUEST['name'];  
   if(!isset($_COOKIE['name']))    
   {
    setcookie('name',$name,0);//The cookie will expire at the end of the session 
   }
```

Comment: Awesome thanks a bunch to everyone who answered, can a cookie be set only for one directory? So if the cookie is set in /setname will the cookie only be identified in /setname or will it work in any other directory?

Comment: in setcookie function set path value to /dirname/,where dirname is the name of directory where you want your cookies to be available.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a bunch everyone. Stackoverflow community is amazing yet again. =]